# setting up Undelivr and Spool folder for CFmail

Tags: coldfusion, smtp, coldfusion-9, cfmail

I am working on an application, and I am trying to get emails undercontrol. All the projects I have worked on since starting ColdFusion hav had the email set up with the Undelivr folder and everything; However, this one does not.

I am unsure how to go about setting up the Undelivr and Spool folders for the cfmail of an application. If someone could point me in the direction of a tutorial on how to set this up or something I would appreciate it.

I have been looking for a solution for this for a couple of hours now and will of course continue to look. The only thing I am getting at the moment however is people having problems and not understanding the spooling, but I understand that part but have never had to set it all up before.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be nothing to "set up". Have you defined your mail server? Have you set it to spool mail messages to disk?

ColdFusion will create those folders for you. They should be under `{ColdFusion}/Mail/Spool` and `{ColdFusion}/Mail/Undelivr`.

Comment: Ok... I am sharing the server with other ColfFusion apps, so I guess what you are saying as they would all share the same spool and undelivr folder?

Comment: Assuming they're all under the same CF instance, yeah.